# iOS6 authenticateHandler is never called

Tags: authentication, gamekit

I have the following code to authenticate local user in GameKit. There are no diagnostics and no crash but the handler is never used and the local user is never authenticated. Can some one say why? This way of authenticating is following the Wenderlich blog on Cocos2d. The ANNOUNCE and CCLOG lines are mine for debugging and they show that the method is called but the handler is not called. The redundant-looking BOOLs are also from debugging. I'm testing on an iOS6 iPhone. This code is in the AppDelegate.

```
-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer {
    ANNOUNCE
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
        [self setLastError:error];
        if ( [CCDirector sharedDirector].isPaused ) [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
        CCLOG(@"inside authenticateHandler");
        if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = YES;
            X.localPlayerAuthenticated = YES;
        } else if (viewController) {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
            [self presentViewController:viewController];
        } else {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = NO;
            X.localPlayerAuthenticated = NO;
        }
    };
    CCLOG(@"lastError: %@", self.lastError);
    CCLOG(@"localPlayer.authenticated: %d", localPlayer.authenticated);
}
```

Comment: Grrr! I ran this several hours later without changing a thing and then it worked! It worked a few times in a row. I guess I should assume that the sandbox game center server wasn't working right earlier. What a pita! I'm still not sure everything is perfect so I won't close the question yet. If anybody has some wisdom to contribute I'd be happy to get it.

Comment: I was out of action all week because of the hurricane (I'm in NYC). Now that I'm back I ran the app from Xcode without changing a thing and the authentication worked as expected. So I have to conclude that the sandbox was not working right, or else that changes to a GC sandbox app take many hours or a day to go into effect.